# Left side isolated granny gear, right side all other gears? Possible and practical?

Tags: gears, hypothetical

To me, the left side on a bike that doesn't have a rear disc brake is being somewhat wasted.

So how about this idea... on the right side have the normal gears but on the left side, have a freewheeling granny gear.  So you would have 2 chains but also some type of clutch so you could switch between the granny gear and the normal gears.  The granny gear could be something incredibly low such as 20/50 but the smallest cog on the main gearset could be much more reasonable such as 34 or even 28.  This would help alleviate the big jump of 10 or more teeth on the granny cog found in MegaRange type gearsets.  By isolating the granny gear, the cassette tooth jumps (between gears) can be made more reasonable.  Perhaps they could even integrate a disc brake and the granny sprocket in one, with the caliper being positioned in the opening where there is no chain.  Perhaps run a concentric ring close to the teeth to hold out any grease from hitting the brake pads. That would be something to behold.

Actually, the granny gear can be enabled all the time since the road speed would almost always exceed that of the granny gear so the pawls on it would not engage.  The lowest normal gear would always be faster than the granny gear, just like if in a gear you pedal at half the speed required to maintain road speed, the gear will not engage the pawls.  When the rider wanted to actually use the granny gear, he/she would have to disable the main gears (via some type of clutch), then pedal fast enough to engage the granny pawls.   So maybe when anticipating a large hill, one could clutch out of the main gears, coast down to walking speed, pedal fast (about 100 RPMs), and then the granny gear would engage.  20/50 (0.4) would be a hell of a hill climbing gear.  With 26" tires, that would be 10.4 gear inches.  Wow!

Also if you were really slick, you could make the granny gear so that the chain is the same length as the main chain so if perhaps your main chain breaks, you have a backup with you.  There are some combinations of sprockets that would make the chain lengths the same (or at least very close).  Also if you rarely use the granny gear, you could half wear out the main chain and then swap them so you get better performance on the main chain and longer gear life.

I know if I had a 20/50 (0.4) low gear I would use it a lot.  That would be awesome.

So the question is can this be made to work and if so, has anyone tried it yet?

Comment: Combination granny sprocket and disc brake is brilliant.   You may want to keep that to yourself and get a patent.   That 3+3+3 idea with dual ramping - no one else is doing it - you may want to check into a patent on that also.

Comment: And your question is? (I don't see a single question mark in the text, and the title doesn't qualify as a full question to me...)

Comment: I put my ideas out so someone can try to make it so we can all benefit.  I am not trying to become rich.  By sharing the idea someone may actually make it and then we can all enjoy it.  Patents take a long time and require a working prototype I think.  I am not a machinist.  Perhaps some retired machinist that is an avid biker can try to make my concept bike and if it works, pitch the idea to bike makers so they can build it.  If I could see one of my bike ideas come to fruition during my lifetime I would be happy.  I have several more too not yet posted.

Comment: You are too generous.  Maybe hold back on some of your best ideas.  There is a patents.stackexchange.com if you want to further explore patents.  You can lock up a provisional patent for like $300 and then pitch your idea(s) to the big boys like SRAM and Shimano.

Comment: I would be happy enough if someone made my ideas a reality.  Yes money would be great but as I said I am not a machinist and would never get a working prototype.  Someone with machining skills can team up with me if they want to since I pitched the idea.  I have what is an even better idea then ones presented here.  I haven't divulged one of my best concepts yet.  It would solve some problems present in even current bike technology.  I am in the central Florida region in case anyone closeby is interested in teaming up on some of these ideas.

Comment: Combination granny sprocket and rear disc brake is not so brilliant cuz the granny chain would have to spin all the time for the rear disc brake to work (unless the combo had some type of freewheel in it too.  That would increase the load/friction.  A prototype would have to be made to check if it is a good workable idea.  I like the fact that an isolated granny gear would free up the regular cogset to more reasonable sizes, thus taking some burden off of the RD.

Comment: Don't let braking get in the way of this brilliant idea.  Put the racket IN the concentric ring close to the teeth to hold out any grease.  Or maybe have the right chainring freewheel.

Comment: Regarding the granny chain, I would prefer if it didn't move all the time cuz the chain speed would be high and a safety risk.  There are many places it could freewheel (rear gear, front gear...) so that seems like a good idea. If both sides freewheel, then when pedaling, both chains will move but the granny gear will not engage since even the lowest right side gear will beat it in speed, thus not allowing the granny pawls to engage.  Conceptually it should work and is not that complicated so I am surprised if nobody has thought of this or made it cuz bikes have been around a very long time.

Comment: Also, I think it would be better to not integrate too many things into one device such as granny gear, disc brake, and freewheel.  I think a better place to freewheel the granny gear would be in the front sprocket assembly which could hold internal oil for good lubrication.  the granny gear disc brake combo also need not be integrated as it can be a piggyback design with a grease shield sandwiched in between them.  Lots of viable solutions.

Comment: I think that this is a lot of complication for something that wouldn't be much benefit over a triple chainring. Using chainrings with 48-36-26 with a 12-30 cassette would give a plenty easy "granny gear" for the hills most people would willing to approach on a bike. Having a 20-50 super-granny gear as you propose would mean you were only going 4.5 km/h at 90 RPM, which is less than walking speed. At that pace, you might as well get off the bike and walk, as it will be more energy efficient.

Comment: David - you seem to have a mad addiction for low low low gearing.   Perhaps your engine needs work, rather than your transmission.

Comment: I did another test today and thru long grass, even when level, my lowest gear (24/28) with a 26" tire which is about 22 1/4 gear inches is way too tall.  Ideally I would like 15 gear inches or less.  I can balance my bike as low as 1 MPH, so slow that sometimes my computer doesn't even register (it reads 0).  I will attempt to remedy this by using 2 magnets instead of 1 and recalibrating for a tire half the diameter (13" instead of 26").  As far an engine vs. tranny, sometimes I like to move the bike with minimal wattage and that is where low gears help a lot.

Comment: Criggie - not an addiction, a need.  Someone else made a 7.5" gear for climbing a 32 degree 0.11 mile incline.  Here is the link:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgIL6eHHgZU

Comment: 0.11 miles at 32 degree  - that is amazing - about 1/2 way it looked like he might stall out.  2 magnets to register under 1 mph - brilliant again.

Comment: This won't work without special equipment. To use stock equipment to get a similar gear range, Just put on a triple crankset with a 22 granny gear in the front and a 10 speed 11-42 cassette in the rear using an MTB clutch rear derailleur from shimano or SRAM. If you want to use road brifters, you'll need to go SRAM, if you want to use friction shifters, your best bet is to go Shimano. You can get around 15 gear inches with a 22 / 40 combo and 700x28mm tires. There would be a lot of chain growth, and you might have issues with cross chaining. Probably want a friction shifter on front derailleur

Comment: The best I can do without spending a lot of time,effort, and money is 20/34 for about 15.3 gear inches.  Once I have the 1 piece crankset off the bike I can tinker around with replacing the 24 with a 20 since it is 58mm BCD. If that is still not low enough I would consider one of those mountain tamer adapters and try to make it work although I doubt it will on my bike.  17/34 would give me the perfect 0.50 low gear I need and desire (13 gear inches).

Comment: @David dude, that YouTube bike was not built to satisfy a **need.** Don't kid yourself.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34761/discussion-on-question-by-david-left-side-isolated-granny-gear-right-side-all-o).

Comment: In practice this is typically done by adding an internal gear hub, or even an internal gear crankset such as the Schlumpf Mountain Drive.  Worst case, all bikes have an extreme hill mode colloquially referred to as "two foot gear" (which is generally not 24 gear inches)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I say it is both possible and practical.  If someone really wants the crawler gear then this is a way to get it without having to resort to other methods such as a double gear reduction (chainring and cogs being only 1 reduction then adding some other one).  If someone ever tries this then please report back.  I would love to have a bike with this isolated very low gear so then I could just use reasonable size cogs and chainrings.